# PHP script has extra 0 at the end of the output on a cellular connection

Tags: php, echo, cellular-network

I have a very simple PHP script as follows:

```
<?php

    echo "$$";

?>
```

On wifi or wired connections, the output is normal, as follows:

```
$$
```

But on my cellular connection (which is LTE on AT&T), the output is:

```
$$0
```

**What's up with the zero in the output?**

The issue only seems to happen on AT&T network, I tried on Verizon network and it was working.

Comment: It's hard to say, we would need a lot of more precisions about your design. However this not seems to be a big problem : i would use a regexp to get result i want.

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to reproduce this … Does this only happen with that specific output (two dollar signs, nothing else)? Does it also happen when you don’t generate that output via PHP, but just request a static file that contains only two dollar signs?

Comment: @CBroe The issue is present no matter what the echo'ed string is. This issue is NOT present when requesting a static file (i.e. text file).

Comment: Well then I’d start by looking at the response the browser receives – is the `0` character part of the actual response body already? Is maybe the `Content-Length` header of? Stuff like that …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding this line of code solved the problem:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Interesting. Any idea why?

Comment: This is just me guessing, but there is something weird with AT&T servers (or whatever machine processes cellular data) that causes the data being transferred to be encoded incorrectly, resulting in unwanted data at the end of the transmission, which comes out as an extra zero on the user end.